# User preferences (home) vanished after a power outage (Ubuntu + MATE)

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, linux-mint, user-profiles, home-directory

After a power outage I've noticed almost nothing in my Ubuntu desktop is as if it was before.

My home folder appears to be just fine, as are my desktop files. However, Compiz had no preferences setup (I had to create launchers on the desktop to run CCSM and then setup stuff like window decoration, moving and resizing). Chrome opened as if was cleanly installed, and I cannot add any panel to my desktop - since none shows, but `mate-panel` is running as usual. My computer appearance is also different - icons and wallpaper, for instance.

I have no idea on how to start fixing this, as at the same time it seems my home folder is gone, but it's not? :(

Currently running Linux Mint 16 (Ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: This question's follow up is on http://askubuntu.com/questions/628256/apps-are-looking-for-home-literally. I cannot delete it yet, as I have given it a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your computer was making some changes to the file system when the power went out. If these were critical files being changed, the system may have noticed file corruption when you turned it back on after the outage and it may have reset your gnome back to factory defaults. This might explain why your files are still there, but any/all custom settings are gone (like you said with chrome, its as if you just installed it).

Unfortunately, there is no "system restore" or "time machine" for ubuntu (at least nothing comes stock with it). There are 3rd party programs like [Timeshift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html) that were made for this exact reason, rolling back system changes whenever necessary.

Comment: also rsnapshot ( open source  time machine script )